# Combine must & must not with match_phrase in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm creating a jobs website where I can search for job descriptions. I've indexed the job descriptions. Now I'm trying to combine two sets of conditions here to retrieve results which must be accurate.

```json
GET index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {"jobdescription": "constructor level 2 required"}
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [ //Must not match phrases which don't contain the word "constructor"
        { "match_phrase": { ????  } },
        { "match_phrase": { ???  } }
     ]
    }
  }
}
```

My aim of the query is to retrieve all the documents which contain the job description as `constructor`
and exclude the documents which don't have that string.

Now some documents may have multiple `job` description entries, e.g a document/result may have 3 job descriptions, a `constructor`, `engineer` and `scientist`, I want to be able to retrieve this also, but exclude or filter out the other two entries i.e. `engineer` & `scientist`.

Not sure if that is possible, any suggestions would be great.

The query above does not retrieve any results. This other query retrieves inaccurate ones.

```json
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {"jobdescription": "constructor level 2 required"}
        }
      ],
      "must": {
         "bool": {
           "must_not": [
              { "match_phrase": {  "jobdescription": "Civil engineer level 6 required"} },
              { "match_phrase": {  "jobdescription": " Chemicals scientist level 7 required" } }
           ]
         }
       }
      }
    }
```

Comment: can you please share your index mapping ?